# ssh yubikey: "Unable to load resident keys: device not found"

Tags: ssh-keys, yubico

I use SSH keys stored on a Yubikey. Today I got the following message when adding my keys to the ssh-agent, as usual:

```
$ ssh-add -K
Enter PIN for authenticator:
Provider "internal" returned failure -4
Unable to load resident keys: device not found
```

There have been no updates to SSH recently. Restarting does not help.

System:

- Mac OS Monterey
- YubiKey 4

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong exactly or how to debug it, but this helped me fix it:

Install the [Yubico Authenticator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/yubico-authenticator/id1497506650?mt=12) app from the Mac App store. Plug in the Yubikey, open the "WebAuthn" section, enter the PIN, and suddenly you can add the SSH keys to your agent again.